# Is there a way to get this to wrap?

Tags: html, css

I have these 2 spans that create the underline with the central writing. Now it happens that the line does not break and therefore goes completely in the row below.

[image: Screenshots]

```css
span.labeled {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: top;
}

span.label {
  display: block;
  text-align: center;
  border-top: 1px solid black;
}
```

Comment: I don't think that's possible

Comment: What happens when the user has a custom stylesheet that increases the font size to 1.5rem?

Comment: Post a [mcve] please

Comment: @TheHeadRush the problem remains

Comment: No, your example must be contained in your question. Don't just link to the site that needs fixing — otherwise, this question will lose any value to future visitors once the problem is solved or if the site you're linking to is inaccessible.For more info, see [Something on my web site doesn't work. Can I just paste a link to it?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/125997/) Thanks!

Comment: I think i have linked all the possible in the first question.. with the current look and the possible, the code of the <span> and a little description of the problem. What else?

Comment: a block level element (`display: block;`) won't wrap like that.

Comment: @RobertoNight Ok, now right click on the text and inspect the element. Make sure you have the entire paragraph selected and add `styel=font-size: 1.5rem` to the tag. Hit enter and reexamine the main browser window The lesson you should learn is that developers don't have the kind of control over the layout that you want them to have.

Comment: @zgood is already inside, in the span.label...

Comment: @RobertoNight I understand that span is inside another span, but that span (the one that you are using for your underline (`border-top: 1px solid black;`) will not wrap like that because it is `display: block;`. It is not possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get close if you don't center the labels:

```css
p {max-width:320px; line-height:3em; font-family:Arial; color:#666; font-size:12px;}
span[title] {position:relative; border-bottom: 1px solid currentColor;}
span[title]::after {
  content:attr(title);
  position:absolute; top:0; left:0; margin-top:.5em;
}
```

```html
<p>The baseball players <span title="A">decided</span> that they <span title="B">all would donate</span> $50 <span title="C">annually</span> to cover the $1,000 sponsor fee for the <span title="D">local youth baseball team</span>. <span title="E">No error.</span></p>
```

Or if you don't mind the labels being left aligned on only the wrapped elements you can try:

```css
p {max-width:320px; line-height:3em; font-family:Arial; color:#666; font-size:12px;}
span[title] {position:relative; border-bottom: 1px solid currentColor;}
span[title]::after {
  content:attr(title);
  position:absolute; top:0; left:0; right:0; text-align:center; margin-top:.5em;
}
```

```html
<p>The baseball players <span title="A">decided</span> that they <span title="B">all would donate</span> $50 <span title="C">annually</span> to cover the $1,000 sponsor fee for the <span title="D">local youth baseball team</span>. <span title="E">No error.</span></p>
```

ONLY TESTED IN CHROME AND SAFARI